# Riddle me this - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

What am I?

> You don't want to be near me,
>
> You'll get chills if you hear me.
>
> You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
>
> But in person I am hard to endure.
>
> Many will argue that it's a Crime
>
> But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time

HINT

> I can be either tangible or intangible

It has already been guessed, but apparently also put on hold..

So here is another hint.

HINT #2

> my path might not be the fastest for you, but it will be the shortest

HINT #3

> Think of homonyms and homographs

Comment: I will give a hint in an hour, if this is not to easy

Comment: guess it is too soon for an hint, don't be so in a hurry to get an answer ;)

Comment: It's not a clue, English just ins't my first language :) Gonna edit it

Comment: you see!? that was supposed to be "isn't" :-D

Comment: @Flying_whale So how often am I supposed to give out hints? I fear that my riddle has to many answers or is too broad?

Comment: @Stender in general it makes sense to wait at least a full day before adding hints, if not longer, so people in all time zones have the opportunity to try the puzzle.  If you think it's too broad, though, you might want to change the puzzle itself (hints are usually optional to make the puzzle easier, not required to get the intended answer).

Comment: @Stender, Is it possible you're thinking of a word which in your language has a meaning which is tangible and meaning which is intangible but that the English equivalent doesn't have such interpretations?

Comment: Lol Donald Trump, except for the last criteria...

Comment: @Asleepace, wow "Trump" actually fits

Comment: Maybe "plagiarism"?

Comment: The word has been guessed!  - my next hint would be "My path might not be the fastest, but it is the shortest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my guess

I think you are:

> Murder

You don't want to be near me

> You don't want to be near the scene of a murder

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> It would be chilling to witness a murder or hear one taking place

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> People always joke about wanting to kill someone

But in person I am hard to endure.

> Again, most people would have a hard time witnessing a murder

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> Most would agree that murder is illegal, but in some cases it could be argued that it is justified

But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time

> I'm not quite sure of this but maybe if someone is desperate they would commit a murder? Or maybe if they are in a situation where they are staring death in the face they would rather commit suicide?

The hint:

> A murder could be a real thing that took place or an intangible version where someone was "murdered by words". If someone says something really mean it is sometimes said the person was murdered by words.

Comment: Ding ding ding ding!!!! You got the word!! 
Regarding the path, I was trying to hone in to this word, by using the fact that it is both a homonym and a homograph - You might be able to make the connection if you think it like that.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are:

> The death (or the Reaper)

```
You don't want to be near me,
```

> All living beings instinctively avoid death.

```
You'll get chills if you hear me.
```

> When you hear something death related you get unconfortable.

```
You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
```

> Sometimes people play Ouija, or very dangerous sports.

```
But in person I am hard to endure.
```

> Meeting death is not fun.

```
Many will argue that it's a Crime
```

> Sometimes the death of someone young can be unfair.

```
But you'll follow my path, if your out of time
```

> When you run out of lifetime, you have to follow the death (or the Reaper)

Comment: The genre is much closer, but still not exactly what i had in my mind.

Answer (score 6):

Shot in the dark, but my first thoughts reading this was

> A ghost

You don't want to be near me,

> People who believe in ghosts, myself included, tend to fear them or actively avoid them if they believe they are near.

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> You ever hear a voice in a quiet area, where you're the only person? Yeah, chill city.

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> Horror movies, horror games, ghosts tend to play a part. Also, Halloween.

But in person I am hard to endure.

> Ghosts can be very unsettling, or very obnoxious in some cases.

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> Yeah, not sure on this line. This is the one that threw me.
>  Although this might be a reference to murder and the belief that ghosts are only born of horrific/tragic deaths?

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> When you're out of time, you die. When you die, you (can, depending on your beliefs) become a ghost.

And the Hint:

> "I can be either tangible or intangible"
>  I believe this is a reference to the fact that ghosts can be intangible, as in can't touch anything, or they can throw things. Technically, though, the poltergeist, the being that commonly throws things, is not actually a ghost but a manifestation of negative energy... But for all intents and purposes, many just lump poltergeist in with ghost.

Comment: Very good answer - but not what I had in mind

Answer (score 5):

Possibly,

> a police siren (or perhaps just a police car)

```
You don't want to be near me,
```

> because it means you've been pulled over, or worse.

```
You'll get chills if you hear me.
```

> That unsettling panicked feeling at hearing a siren behind you, even if you're doing nothing wrong!

```
You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
```

> Police sirens show up in movies and TV all the time.
>  Or, many people play with toy police cars as children.

```
But in person I am hard to endure.
```

> But in person they're loud and disquieting

```
Many will argue that it's a Crime
```

> When a crime's been committed, police often show up, sirens blaring.

```
But you'll follow my path, if your out of time
```

> If you're late, following a police car means you'll get all the green lights (in many cities anyway, where traffic lights switch for emergency vehicles) and, with cars ahead of the police car pulling over to yield the right of way, you'll have a relatively open road ahead as well.

Comment: Really nice answer, but not was I was thinking of :)

Comment: I was thinking ambulance, it seemed clearer re: hard to endure (hurt and needing an ambulance), and the relation of lawyers chasing ambulance being related to crime.  Doesn't match the hint, though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> a lie

```
You don't want to be near me,
```

> you don't want to be friend of someone whose a liar

```
You'll get chills if you hear me.
```

> you'll not be comfortable when you realize someone lied to you.

```
You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
```

> many people lie to others as a joke, especially in April fools.

```
But in person I am hard to endure.
```

> but you won't be so happy if the joke is on you.

```
Many will argue that it's a Crime
```

> lying is a crime in some religions

```
But you'll follow my path, if your out of time
```

> But everyone lies if he has no other option.

Comment: This just took a whole new direction! not was I was looking for, but it fits very well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are:

> A draft

```
You don't want to be near me,
```

> Drafts (wind) are annoying

```
You'll get chills if you hear me.
```

> Drafts (wind) are often cold

```
You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
```

> Drafts (sports) are entertainment for many people

```
But in person I am hard to endure.
```

> Drafts (picks, winds) are annoying

```
Many will argue that it's a Crime
```

> Draft (military) are often criticized

```
But you'll follow my path, if your out of time
```

> “May the odds be ever in your favour!”

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Interesting answer. Though some seem a little stretched. What about the hint? And can you clarify your explanation of the last sentence?

Comment: Sorry, the last sentence was a bit of a joke... it was a reference to Hunger Games as Katniss was drafted into the games.

Comment: Aaah. I get it. Hahaha

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are:

> Violence

You don't want to be near me,

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> Violence is a scary thing for sure, we strive to avoid it and the screams that accompany it.

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

But in person I am hard to endure.

> Violence is an exceptionally popular form of entertainment, but is always horrific in real life.

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> It often is a crime, but there are times when violence is in a grey area of the law. Should one go to prison for throwing a punch? What about in self defense?

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> While often thought of as not being the solution, violence is frequently a last resort.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense, but not what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

> A smartphone!

```
You don't want to be near me,
```

> Maybe it's just me, but I'm really tired of smartphones

```
You'll get chills if you hear me.
```

> Those stupid ringtones, always going off at the wrong time

```
You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
```

> Candy Crush!  Flappy Bird!

```
But in person I am hard to endure.
```

> Those stupid digital assistants

```
Many will argue that it's a Crime
But you'll follow my path, if your out of time
```

> GPS

Comment: Hahaha - I understand your logic, but the answer is way of.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a

> Psycho /Psychic person

As

You don't want to be near me,

> Nobody prefers to be near to a psycho

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> Usually, it is the case.

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> The famous A Hitchcock movie...

But in person I am hard to endure.

> Difficult to bear a or lead a life as a psycho

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> Though it's a mental disorder.... seen as a crime ( the actions of a psycho)

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> When out of time, people may get tizzy..(resembling psychic behaviour...)

Comment: Very interesting, have not thought of that. So not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> War

You don't want to be near me

> You don't want to be near a war zone.

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> You can get chills you hear of the destruction caused by war.

But in person I am hard to endure.

> War is hard to endure.

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> War can be argued as a Crime.

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> You would go for war if no option(or time) is available. Sometimes if there is no other way you have to fight.

HINT

> War can be tangible or intangible.

Comment: Very nice answer, fits all the hints etc - but not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

you might be a

> Sonic Boom

You don't want to be near me:

> Sonic Booms can be quite powerful and can easily shatter windows

You'll get chills if you hear me:

> They create huge amounts of sound energy like a deafening explosion

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure:

> People like to watch sonic booms at air shows and they find it fascinating

But in person I am hard to endure:

> The shock waves produced are hard to endure and cause damage

Many will argue that it's a Crime:

> Noise regulations do not allow commercial aircrafts to go supersonic

But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time:

> If you run out of time, you need to go supersonic

Answer (score 1):

Are You:

> Fear itself

```
You don't want to be near me,
```

> You do not want to be near anything you are afraid of

```
You'll get chills if you hear me.
```

> Cold sweats and shivers are common reactions to fear

```
You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
```

> People are fans of horror movies

```
But in person I am hard to endure.
```

> It is hard for a person to overcome their fear

```
Many will argue that it's a Crime
```

> Usually things people fear are related to crime

```
But you'll follow my path, if your out of time
```

> Yah I don't know about this one

```
Hint:
```

> Fear can be both tangible and intangible

Comment: Very good answer! not was I was looking for though.

Comment: I hope I never meat "tangible" fear

Comment: What you've never had goosebumps?

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be based on Raul Torry's answer:

> A dead person

You don't want to be near me,

> you don't want to be near a dead person

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> You get scared if you hear that somebody died

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> There are dead people in many action movies or terror movies.

But in person I am hard to endure.

> It's hard to face dead in reality

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> Somebody kill him.

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> We have to die sometime.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please take the tour to see our community's expectations, you'll also get a badge! Just a heads up, in the future, make sure you hide your answers in a spoiler block. You can do this by using `>!` instead of just `>`

Comment: Again, the genre is close, but also way of. :)

Comment: or not way of, maybe both?

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> the rain

You don't want to be near me,

> You want to stay far away

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> The sound made by rain can help people concentrate or sleep.

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> dancing in the rain

But in person I am hard to endure.

> rain can come as hail

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> rain that comes as hail can destroy cars

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> You have the option to go throw rain if you don't have a place to stay,but it's not safe

I can be either tangible or intangible

> depending on how much it rains

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> Devil

You don't want to be near me

> Simply you don't want to be near the devil.

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> You'll get chills by thinking about devil ,hell and all that

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> Tv shows,cinema,songs..

But in person I am hard to endure.

> Devil is a pain in the ass

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> not sure about this one

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> You always end up following his path once stuck in hard times

Comment: You should input spoiler tags - you do that by writing `>!`instead of just `>` anyway- good answer, but not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are:

> Pain

You don't want to be near me,

> People for example tend to avoid hospitals

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> People screaming in pain

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> Pain in movies, games where you get little electric shocks, boxing etc.

But in person I am hard to endure.

> Being in pain yourself for quite a while sucks

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> Inflicting pain on others is a crime in a lot of cases

But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time

> Running to catch bus or train and being out of breath - legs hurting - but still running

HINT

> Tangible if you have pain somewhere on your body, but there is also mental pain, sorrow missing somebody etc.

Comment: Clever answer, nut not quite the word I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> The red ghost from Pac-man

```
You don't want to be near me,
```

> You run away from it because it kills you

```
You'll get chills if you hear me.
```

> The sort of wewwewwew sound the ghosts make

```
You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure
```

> Well it's a game

```
But in person I am hard to endure.
```

> When met in person you will die

```
Many will argue that it's a Crime
```

> You can argue the red is actually a crimson color

```
But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time
```

> When the time on the big dot is running out and you're trying to catch the ghost

Oh and the hint:

> It's intangible normally for pac-man and tangible when it's blue I guess

Comment: Hahaha - We are definitely heading a new direction with this guess - but not what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess that is the answer

> Black magic

You don't want to be near me,

> Although not many people believe in black magic and all that stuff but still there is a number of people who believe in this stuff and don't want to be near it.

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> These superstitious people usually get scared of these things as they're considered to be bad omen.

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> It is shown in many movies and this concept of black magic is largely used for drama etc as for entertainment purpose.

But in person I am hard to endure.

> It is believed by many people that the results of black magic are hard to endure and result in misfortune.

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> It is considered as a crime practicing black magic in any form.

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> A number of superstitious people still believe that black magic can help them achieve goal they desire and they even consider it as a shortcut path to their goals when they fail to get them by normal means and are out of time.

Comment: I see your guess makes sense, but not the word I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> A shot

You don't want to be near me,

> people usually don't like to stay near a shooting

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> people get chills when they hear a shot

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> people play videogames (fps) or use guns to hunt as an entertainment

But in person I am hard to endure.

> get shot is not nice

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> if you shot someone innocent with a gun will be a crime

But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time

> If someone is trying to kill you or your beloved ones and you have a gun in your hands you will perhaps defend yourself or your family/friends/etc.

I can be either tangible or intangible

> well you can get shot or just hear it.

Comment: Nice answer! it fits all the way down - But not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Guns/Gunfire?

You don't want to be near me

> If there's gunfire near me, I'd want to get as far from it as I can.

You'll get chills if you hear me

> When the realization arrives that what you're hearing is in fact a gun going off, you would get chills.

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> Shooting ranges to practice, or video games (CoD, CS:GO, etc.)

But in person, I am hard to endure

> The sound of a gun going off near you is loud and unpleasant.

Many will argue that it's a crime

> Arguments that war is a crime in itself, shootings, murder.

But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time

> Out of time could refer to perhaps feeling like you're all out of options, so you turn to a life of violence. It could also refer to you running out of options to defend yourself, so you'd take the shot despite not wanting to.

Comment: Very similar to Victorias answer, So you'll get the same comment : Nice answer! it fits all the way down - But not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> Suicide

You don't want to be near me,

> People are uncomfortable with the subject. Often places where suicide has taken place remains uninhabited.

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> Suicide is horrific. We do not like to hear that someone we knew has committed suicide.

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> Suicide is often used in books and movies to develop the plot.

But in person I am hard to endure.

> The conscious decision to suicide is very tough. It is also hard to approach a suicidal person with the aim of convincing them to look forward to life.

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> It is considered to be a crime in many nations and religions.

But you'll follow my path, if you're out of time

> Once you commit suicide there is no going back to life. It is the one mistake you won't live to regret.

Comment: Very nice, but not excactly what I had in mind

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

> Scream

You don't want to be near me

> The guy from the horror movie

You'll get chills if you hear me.

> Screaming is scary

You use me as entertainment, of that I'm sure

> Horror movies/thrillers

But in person I am hard to endure.

> The guy again

Many will argue that it's a Crime

> Screaming can be associated with a crime

But you'll follow my path, if your out of time

> When someone screams, you can get scared and scream too?

Comment: Interesting answer, but i wouldn't say that a scream is tangible?

Comment: Yeah, true. Well not sure then. Maybe something like music? You can feel it, and it can give you chills? But I'm clueless haha